# Keep a ".hover" animated element on screen after navigating to it from trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope my title wasn't too long, this is also my first question so bear with me.

So I have a set of divs within my .navicons div that I want to serve as triggers for offscreen element/s (#wdFoot, #wpFoot, #gdFoot) to raise into view from the bottom of the screen on hover. I have this effect working so far using .hover and .animate but for usability I would like for the animated footer elements to stay raised or in the screen area when the user moves their mouse from the trigger area to the actual foot elements that have just raised into screen view.

here's what I Have so far.

```
<div class="navicons">
    <div id="wdicon"><!-- trigger divs  -->
        Wd
    </div>
    <div id="wpicon">
        Wp
    </div>
    <div id="gdicon">
        Gd
    </div>
</div>

<section id="wdFoot"class="footNav"><!-- after they appear on the screen I want these to stay visible when the user moves the mouse from the triggers to this area  -->
    <h2>Wd Foot</h2>
</section>

<section id="wpFoot"class="footNav">
    <h2>Wp Foot</h2>
</section>

<section id="gdFoot"class="footNav">
    <h2>Gd Foot</h2>
</section>
```

CSS//

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.navicons{
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
.navicons > div{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border:2px solid rgba(178,178,178,.08);
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:all .05s;
}
.navicons > div:hover{
    border:2px solid #1f88e1;
}
section.footNav{
  width:100%;
  height:240px;
  background-color:rgba(51,51,51,.7);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-240px;
}
```

jQuery//

```
$( '#wdicon' ).hover(function() {
     $( "#wdFoot" ).animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
  },function(){
     $("#wdFoot").animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
  });

$( '#wpicon' ).hover(function() {
     $( "#wpFoot" ).animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
  },function(){
     $("#wpFoot").animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
  });

$( '#gdicon' ).hover(function() {
     $( "#gdFoot" ).animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
  },function(){
     $("#gdFoot").animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
  });
```

Here's my [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljveyzn/)

Also, I'm sure there's an easier or shorter way to write my jQuery so feel free to let me know.

Thank you

Comment: OK, but when should than they disappear?

Comment: i.e: I hover the first icon, I move the mouse away, you want it's related panel  element to stay "up".... but should that element ever slide back down?

Comment: They should disappear when either you leave the trigger area and when you also leave the footer area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible option. It all depends on what actions should cause the footer to be removed. In this example, the footer will remain visible for at least 1 full second, giving the user enough time to move the cursor over the footer. Once over the footer, moving the cursor away will dismiss it immediately. Other approaches are possible using the `setTimeout` function as I've done here.

First, I decided to use a `data` attribute to remove the need for multiple `hover` calls:

```
<div class="navicons">
    <div id="wdicon" data-hover="wdFoot">
        Wd
    </div>
    <div id="wpicon" data-hover="wpFoot">
        Wp
    </div>
    <div id="gdicon" data-hover="gdFoot">
        Gd
    </div>
</div>

<section id="wdFoot"class="footNav">
    <h2>Wd Foot</h2>
</section>

<section id="wpFoot"class="footNav">
    <h2>Wp Foot</h2>
</section>

<section id="gdFoot"class="footNav">
    <h2>Gd Foot</h2>
</section>
```

Then I used `setTimeout` to delay the dismissal animation for 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

```
var dismissTimeout;

var dismiss = function($group) {
    $group.animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
};

$( '[data-hover]' ).hover(function() {
    $(".footNav").stop().css('bottom':'-240px');
    $( "#" + $(this).data("hover") ).stop().animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
},function(){
    dismissTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        dismiss($("#" + $(this).data("hover") ));
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

Since the `dismissTimeout` variable is in the outer scope, it can be cleared in a `hover` event handler on the footer:

```
$('.footNav').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(dismissTimeout);
}, function() {
    dismiss($(this));
});
```

[Try it in my fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/70mvLssy/3/).

To animate the dismissal of inactive footers when the next item is hovered, just replace the `css` call with `animate`:

```
 $(".footNav").stop().animate({'bottom': '-240px'}, 500);
```

This is demonstrated in [version 5 of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/70mvLssy/5/).

For height animations that coincide with the vertical movement, try [Version 6](https://jsfiddle.net/70mvLssy/6/). The basic idea is to add the return to normal height to the `dismiss` function animation:

```
var dismiss = function($group) {
    $group.stop().animate({'bottom':'-240px', 'height': '240px'}, 500);
};
```

Then add the animation increasing the height to the footer `hover` handler:

```
$('.footNav').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(dismissTimeout);
    $(this).animate({'height': '600px'}, 500);
}, function() {
    dismiss($(this));
});
```

You'll also notice version 6 removes two of the `stop()` calls, as they can end up cancelling dismissal animations already underway, which is no good.

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the animation (both up and down) when switching from trigger to trigger? Right now the .footNav disappears if you move from trigger to trigger with the newly hovered .footNav doing its upward animation. Also, your fiddle works great but I cannot get it to work in my doc. I'm working in Dreamweaver. Thanks

Comment: I got it to work. This was pretty much exactly what I was trying to do. But after seeing the effect of the opaque backgrounds of the footer panels, I'd like to still see that. but it's not a deal breaker lol. Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: Just change the `.css` in the `.hover` handler to a `.animate({...}, 500)`.

Comment: Perfect. If I could just pick your brain for one more solution that would make this function a bit better.....I want the footer's height to animate from 240px to about 600px when the user hovers onto it. I added a hover function to animate the height and it worked on the way up, but it didn't dismiss correctly and was still partially visible on the scree.

Comment: That's kind of its own question, but sure. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

First of, you should definitely use `.stop()` to prevent animations buildups on fast mouse movements. A shorter way to do the same ***[would be](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljveyzn/1/)***:

```
$(".navicons [id$=icon]").hover(function( e ) {
    var pr = this.id.split("icon")[0];   // the ID prefix
    var mE = e.type==="mouseenter";      // is mouseenter?
    $("#"+ pr +"Foot" ).stop().animate({bottom: mE ? 0 : -240}, 500);
});
```

To keep the element opened you cannot simply use `hover`, you need to create a **timeout** (if you want your bottom element to wait for the mouse to enter in order to cancel that timeout - but that all depends on what you want to achieve *which you did not explained clearly*)

**Since you did not requested any timeout:**

> *I would like for the animated footer elements to stay raised or in the screen area when the user moves their mouse from the trigger area to the actual foot elements that have just raised into screen view*

***[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3Ljveyzn/2/)***:

```
var $activeFoot,

$(".navicons > div").add( $activeFoot ).hover(function( e ) {
    // If any active exists, animate-off
    if($activeFoot) $activeFoot.stop().animate({bottom: -240}, 500); 
    // Create a new active
    $activeFoot = $("#"+ this.id.split("icon")[0] +"Foot");
    // Animate-in the current active 
    $activeFoot.stop().animate({bottom: 0}, 500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just based on what I've read in the initial question, I threw this together.

```
$( '#wdicon' ).hover(function() {
    $( "#wdFoot" ).stop().animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
    $("#gdFoot, #wpFoot").stop().animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
});

$( '#wpicon' ).hover(function() {
  $( "#wpFoot" ).stop().animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
  $("#wdFoot, #gdFoot").stop().animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
});

$( '#gdicon' ).hover(function() {
  $( "#gdFoot" ).stop().animate({'bottom':'0'}, 500);
  $("#wdFoot, #wpFoot").stop().animate({'bottom':'-240px'}, 500);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aegmqfjx/

Basically, when hovering over one button, you tell the other footers to hide while the footer for your button slides up.

As others have said, you should definitely use .stop or some other clearing function to prevent animations from stacking up when a user goes nuts over the buttons with their mouse.